# Webpack error: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've been setting up a personal project with react, but getting an error I couldn't find answer to. Webpack keeps giving the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/Home.js
Module parse failed: 
/Users/LandonKoo/projects/lktheprogrammer/app/components/Home.js Unexpected token (5:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| class Home extends Component{
|   render() {
|     return (<h1>Hey!!!! Home!!</h1>);
|   }
| }
@ ./app/src/index.js 11:12-44
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "lktheprogrammer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blog for LK the Programmer",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "watch": "webpack -d --watch",
  "production": "webpack -p"
},
"author": "Landon Koo <landonkoo0207@gmail.com>",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
  "webpack": "^2.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
},
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "react-router": "^2.8.1"
}
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/dist');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I've been stuck for hours for this. Any comment will be very grateful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create .babelrc file

```
//./.babelrc
{
    "presets":[
        "es2015", "react"
    ]
}
```

or specify presets as loader options

```
{
    test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include : APP_DIR,
    exclude : /node_modules/,
    loader : 'babel-loader',
    query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
}
```

Comment: I have .babelrc file exactly like you mentioned. I'm sorry for leaving that out. Can you think of any other reason for causing this? Thanks for responding anyways! :)

Comment: I've figured it out. It's turned out I put the component in the wrong place. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LandonKoo Can you explain how you solved the problem. I am also stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

use 'react-hot' loader also, 
Please refer https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173

Answer (score 0):

for me it was that my jsx files had uppercase JSX extension

test : /.(js|jsx)$/,
does not find uppercase JSX, so that needed to become
test: /.(js|jsx|JSX|JS)$/,

or rename uppercase JSX filename extension to lowercase jsx would work too